# How to debug if app closes without error message?

Tags: swift, xcode

Im facing an issue that i am unable to debug.

If i open the app, it opens normally and works. But if i launch the app and close the app within 1 second and then launch the app again, it crashes without error message.

How do i debug this as Xcode loses debug connection if i close the app?

I tried putting exception break point but since xcode loses debug connection, it wont trigger.

This ONLY happens when a user does the above mentioned steps (open, close within 2 seconds and open again).

Is there anyway to find out why the app is closing and why there is no error / crash message?

Clarification : The crash happens when user opens the app, within 1 sec terminates the app by manually by swiping up from recents menu and tries to open the app again within 1 or 2 seconds. (Open -> terminate -> open)

Comment: So it's crashing exactly on relaunching after app unloading? There is launch options in the product schema. Choose  `wait for the executable to be launched` instead of `Automatic`.

Comment: @Rob Yes close as in terminate by swiping up from home. Also i added Firebase Crashlytics and whats weird is that, even after multiple tries it isnt sending anything and it didnt fine anything.

Answer (score 1):

Let us imagine that you run the app and quickly force-quit. Then, if you start your second run of the app from the Xcode debugger, hopefully, you should see your crash in Xcode at that point.

If that does not work, you might consider a crash reporting tool (e.g., Crashlytics, [etc.](https://www.g2.com/products/crashlytics/competitors/alternatives)). That will help you monitor and track crash reports that happen (for both you and your users) in the wild. If you do this, make sure you test the crash reporting system with some forced crash/report because an absence of a report could just be a result of a misconfiguration, which is easy to do because the setup of these tools takes a little work the first time you do it. Just make sure you have the crash report system working with a positive crash report before you draw any conclusions from an absence of a crash report generated by this particular bug.

That having been said, the way these crash reporting systems often work is they capture the crash and send it the next time you start up the app. It seems like there might be a chance that your particular crash (firing it up after having quickly force-quit it the first time) is happening so fast that the crash reporting system may not have a chance to send off its report of the past crash. (That having been said, these are still invaluable for capturing information about user crashes that happen during the normal use of the app, so I would consider them even if it does not help in this particular scenario.)

So, let’s imagine that you are still unsuccessful in catching your crash for some reason. The last resort is to consider sprinkling your code with `Logger`/`OSLog` statements. The nice thing about these logging statements is that you can watch these logging statements on your macOS Console app. See WWDC 2020 [Explore logging in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10168/).

Comment: Thanks. This issue only happens on real device. Whats weird is that, this ONLY happens if there are other apps in the recent app list on the phone. If there are NO other apps running, this crash doesn't happen. I assume it has something to do with memory (??)
I tried crashlytics but this error isnt captured on crashlytics.


Any idea why this only happens in very specific scenario?

Comment: “The issue only happens on a real device.” Still, that doesn’t mean you shouldn’t be able to run that second invocation from your Xcode debugger on your device. That having been said, the debugger changes enough of the app lifecycle that it might affect that behavior which you are trying to observe (i.e., a “Heisenbug”). Still, judicious `Logger` and/or `OSLog` statements might help you identify where it is crashing. No immediate causes leap to my mind, though…